# How many positive integers $k$ between $1$ and $100$ are such that $\frac{7}{k+7}$ have the form $\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{a_i}{15^i}$ with $a_i\in\Bbb{I}$?

Tags: contest-math

> Let a fraction that can be expressed by the sum $\;\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{a_i}{15^i}$, where $a_i \in \Bbb I$  is a $15$-based fraction.
>
> Then find how many positive integer $k$ between $1$ and $100$  are there such that $\frac{7}{k+7}$ is a $15$-based fraction. (Source: IJSO first round test.)

I tried letting $a_j$ be the smallest number in $\{a_1,a_2,...,a_k\}$ and let $a_l$ be the largest number in $\{a_1,a_2,...,a_k\}$, to create an inequality, but that isn't working.

Comment: What is $\Bbb I$?

Comment: You need $\frac 7{n+7}$ to terminate within $n$ terms in base $15$, so $n+7$ must divide $15^n$

Comment: @Arthur $\Bbb I$ is a set of integer I guess.